# Contacts list in Pantheon-mail

Tags: pantheon-mail

I have problems in list of contacts of Pantheon-mail.
I found that it is not possible to manage this list within mail
and that no additional tool can do the job !
Where are located the data files of Pantheon-mail ?

Answer (score 2):

You can find pantheon-mail's data in `~/.local/share/pantheon-mail/`. Inside this folder you'll find a folder for each email account. Inside each account folder you'l find an attachements folder, a geary.ini file, and a geary.db file. The geary.db file can be opened with any SQLite client. [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/dl/) works great: `sudo apt install sqlitebrowser`. The ContactTable contains everything related to the Contacts from the elementary OS email client.

EDIT: [Sequeler](https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.alecaddd.sequeler/) also works fine, and it's designed for elementary OS :)